# Testing http.Server.close error in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, testing

I have a code in NodeJS responsible to close an http.Server connection and I would like to test the error scenario on the http.Server.close() method.

The problem is to do that, I need to simulate the return of the close method with the err object populated, and I don't know how to do it.

Below you can find my code and I would like to test the line where we can find the code `reject(err);`

Note: In my integration tests, I'm starting temp HTTP servers to simulate the real scenario. So as far as I understood I need to find a real scenario where the .close method will be rejected by the default implementation.

Thanks.

```js
this._httpServer = http.createServer((req: http.IncomingMessage, res: http.ServerResponse) => this.handler(req, res));
...
disconnect(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this._httpServer.close((err) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve();
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Based on the official documentation, the unique error scenario is when we are trying to close an already closed server.

So, to make the test work, before calling my `disconnect` method I only need to close the httpServer (`this._httpServer.close()`).

Reference: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/net.html#net_server_close_callback